# How do I process this typedef?

Tags: c

I have an assignment that requires me to generate a 10 by 10 grid, with each grid either being empty or populated with an asterisk. The startup code includes the pattern it's supposed to be generated in, but I'm just unsure how to process it.

In the helper file, this typedef is declared

```
#define BOARD_WIDTH 10
#define BOARD_HEIGHT 10

typedef enum cell{
    EMPTY,
    BLOCKED,
    PLAYER
} Cell;

#define EMPTY_OUTPUT " "
#define BLOCKED_OUTPUT "*"

Cell BOARD_1[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];
Cell BOARD_2[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];
```

and here's the code in the c file

```
Cell BOARD_1[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH] =
{
    { BLOCKED, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },
    { EMPTY, BLOCKED, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLOCKED, EMPTY, EMPTY },
    { EMPTY, EMPTY, BLOCKED, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },
    { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLOCKED, EMPTY, EMPTY },
    { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLOCKED, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },
    { EMPTY, EMPTY, BLOCKED, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLOCKED, EMPTY, BLOCKED, EMPTY, EMPTY },
    { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLOCKED, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },
    { EMPTY, EMPTY, BLOCKED, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },
    { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY },
    { EMPTY, EMPTY, BLOCKED, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLOCKED }
};
```

I wrote a bit of code to generate a blank grid

```
void initialiseBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH])
{
int x;
int y;
printf("| |");
for(x=0; x<=9; x++){
    printf("%i|", x);
}
printf("\n");
for (y=0; y<=9; y++){

    printf("|%i|", y);
    for(x=0; x<=9; x++){
        printf(" |");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

}
void loadBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH],
           Cell boardToLoad[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH])
{
    /* TODO */
}
```

But I'm unsure how to use the `BOARD_1` cell to populate the grid with asterisks. 
This function `initialiseBoard()` is also part of the startup code, I would also like an explanation as to why there is a need for the argument when I'm generating a blank grid.

Comment: You should use `BOARD_HEIGHT` and `BOARD_WIDTH` in the `for` loops instead of 9

Comment: I would have written this as `typedef enum {  EMPTY=' ', BLOCKED='*', PLAYER ='@' } Cell;` and then just cast the value to `char` when you want to print it. Saves you a look-up table. The alternative would be a look-up table: `const char SYMBOL[] = {' ', '*', '@'};` followed by `SYMBOL[my_enum]`.

Answer (score 2):

"Generate" doesn't mean "print to standard output", it means "create in-memory state", in other words your `initialiseBoard()` function is supposed to *change* the contents of the board array its passed, so that it becomes an initialized board (rather than a random non-initialized board).

The `printf()`s in your loops should be assignments to cells of `board`:

```
void initialiseBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH])
{
  for (size_t y = 0; y < BOARD_HEIGHT; ++y)
  {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < BOARD_WIDTH; ++x)
      board[y][x] = EMPTY;
  }
}
```

This sets all cells to `EMPTY`.